# Conditionally update nested object value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following nested object to update after some conditions.based on the condition finally iwant to update `promotional` or `transactional` value

```
{
    "_id" : "XX1",   
    "credit" : {
        "sms" : {
            "credit" : {
                "promotional" : 0,
                "transactional" : 1231
            }
        },
        "viber" : {
            "credit" : {
                "promotional" : 10,
                "transactional" : 50
            }
        },
        "whatsapp" : {
            "credit" : {
                "promotional" : 30,
                "transactional" : 40
            },            
        }
    },
}
```

conditions will based on the passing variable values

```
 accountId = "XX1",
 channel = "sms",
 messageType = "promotional",
 credit = 150
```

these are the conditions should check befor update

- `_id` should match with `accountId`
- if `channel='sms'`,it should select `credit.sms`
- if  `messageType = "promotional"` then check promotional value is greater than to `credit` or not
- if it is greater than to `credit` value (credit.sms.credt.promotional) should update with : `(credit.sms.credt.promotional)-credit`

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Computed property name* and [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator to do it. Something like:

```
YourModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: accountId, [`credit.${channel}.credit.${messageType}`]: { $gte: credit } },
  { $inc: { [`credit.${channel}.credit.${messageType}`]: -credit} }
)
```

Comment: thanks it works for greater than values.also if it is less than to credit,i want to assign current credit.${channel}.credit.${messageType} into variable and update document record into `0`